# Birt report internationalization using datasource instead of resource properties files

Tags: internationalization, datasource, birt

I created the following report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
<property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.6.0.v201606072122</property>
<simple-property-list name="includeResource">
    <value>Resources</value>
</simple-property-list>
<property name="units">in</property>
<method name="beforeFactory"><! 
[CDATA[reportContext.getDesignHandle().setStringProperty("locale",
params["__locale"].value);]]></method>
<property name="iconFile">/templates/blank_report.gif</property>
<property name="bidiLayoutOrientation">ltr</property>
<property name="imageDPI">96</property>
<parameters>
    <scalar-parameter name="__locale" id="8">
        <property name="valueType">static</property>
        <property name="dataType">string</property>
        <property name="distinct">true</property>
        <list-property name="selectionList"/>
        <property name="paramType">simple</property>
        <property name="controlType">text-box</property>
        <structure name="format">
            <property name="category">Unformatted</property>
        </structure>
    </scalar-parameter>
</parameters>
<page-setup>
    <simple-master-page name="Simple MasterPage" id="2">
        <page-footer>
            <text id="3">
                <property name="contentType">html</property>
                <text-property name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-property>
            </text>
        </page-footer>
    </simple-master-page>
</page-setup>
<body>
    <label id="7">
        <text-property name="text" key="offerte.offerte"></text-property>
    </label>
    <label id="9">
        <text-property name="text" key="offerte.klant"></text-property>
    </label>
</body>
```

It works great, but now I want to use a datasource instead of the properties file. Anyone know where to start?

Answer (score 0):

A properties file is the "standard" way to support internationalization in BIRT, but you can do it any way you like.

For example, in our application we are using a SQL database. All the translations are storend in tables. The output language is specified as a report parameter. Each and every translation is done on this basis.

For example, we are never using labels. Instead, we use dynamic text items (with plain text or html depending on the circumstances.

A little javascript function pr(x) returns the translation for a text x.

We do all the date and number formatting with SQL if possible (I don't know if it is possible to change the "format date" and "format number" properties dynamically - this might work as well).

Comment: could you elaborate on the javascript function?

Comment: The idea is: Use pr("some text") to get the translation into the target language (for example: "Irgendein Text" in German) in the layout. The report uses uses a Javascript object (eg a report variable) to store the translations. The pr function just gets the translation from that object. You fill the Javascript object once at the top of the report using a SQL datasets and the onFetch event. This is for the static texts (labels etc). It is easy to scan the XML source (during development) for pr("...") to see which labels have to be translated. For dynamic data, do it in SQL directly.